# How to merge object of array and only increase amount property? Javascript array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am creating a recipe book application in Angular 7 which has a shopping list feature.

What I want:

When a person adds recipe ingredients to shopping list twice
it increases only the amount of the ingredient obj.amount.

What Happens:

When a person clicks add an ingredient to the shopping list twice
it creates another object of the same properties and shows the ingredient twice in the list.

What I want:

When someone clicks add ingredient twice it increases the object.amount where object.name are the same rather than creating a new object and showing a new list.

```
import { Ingredients } from './ingredient.model';
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

export class ShoppingListService {
  ingredientsChanged = new EventEmitter<Ingredients[]>();
  ingredient: Ingredients[] = [
    new Ingredients('Apple', 10),
    new Ingredients('Banana', 10)
  ];

  getData() {
    return this.ingredient.slice();
  }
  addIngredient(ingredient: Ingredients) {
    this.ingredient.push(ingredient);
    this.ingredientsChanged.emit(this.ingredient.slice());
  }
  toShoppingList(ingredient: Ingredients[])
  //I want to detect duplicate ingredient obj and increase 
  //ingredient.amount 
  //having same ingredient name 
  //i.e. suppose I add Apple again with amount 5
  //it should change the amount of {new Ingredient('Apple',15)} but should 
  //not 
  //create new object.
  {
    // METHOD 1 Loop through the array and add each element one by one
    for (let ing of ingredient) {
      this.addIngredient(ing);
    }
    // METHOD 2 : Add all ingredients at once
    // this.ingredient.push(...ingredient);
  }
}
```

[Person Clicks ToShopping List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXcKs.png)
[Output of Shopping List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eni2p.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your `Ingredients` model has a way to retrieve the `name` and `quantity` of an ingredient. Something like

```
const apples = new Ingredients('Apple',10);

apples.name; // should return 'Apple'
apples.quantity; // should return 10

apples.quantity = 15; // should set the quantity to 15
apples.quantity; // should now return 15
```

In which case, the simplest solution would be to check if an ingredient exists in your array before adding it. Something like

```
function toShoppingList(ingredients = []) {
    const list = [];
    for (const ingredient of ingredients) {
        const { name, quantity } = ingredient;
        const existingIngredient = list.filter(item => item.name === name)[0];
        if (existingIngredient) {
            existingIngredient.quantity += quantity;
        } else {
            list.push(new Ingredients(name, quantity));
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Ingredient model is a class as following:                                                              
          export class Ingredients{ public name:string;
          public amount:number;
          constructor(name:string,amount:number){
          this.name=name;
          this.amount=amount;
          } 
       }

Comment: toShoppingList is taking arrays of ingredients as input from recipeIngredient array and then pushing each ingredient into the shoppingList original array of ingredients